# Lua: How do I calculate a random number between 50 and 500, with an average result of 100?

Tags: math, lua, distribution

I think this is a log-normal distribution? I'm not sure. The lua I have is here:

```
local min = 50
local max = 500
local avg = 100
local fFloat = ( RandomInt( 0, avg ) / 100 ) ^ 2 -- float between 0 and 1, squared
local iRange = max - min -- range of min-max
local fDistribution = ( ( fFloat * iRange ) + min ) / 100
finalRandPerc = fDistribution * RandomInt( min, max ) / 100
```

It is close to working, but sometimes generates numbers that are slightly too large.

Comment: Well, if it's important to get exactly the right mean, and the shape of the distribution doesn't have to be anything in particular, try a mixture of uniform distributions, one on [50, 100], and the other on [100, 500]. I.e. choose the first one w/ probability p and the other with 1 - p. The mean of a mixture is p mean1 + (1 - p) mean2, so you want p times 75 + (1 - p) times 300 = 100, that gives p = 8/9 if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Your question is vague as there are numerous random distributions with a mean of 100 and a range of [50, 500].  Also, saying "between _a_ and _b_" is likewise vague here.   Indeed, one solution among many is to choose 500 with probability 1/9 and 50 otherwise.  See also [this question with a similarly vague request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66941506/generating-random-natural-numbers-with-higher-probability-for-lower-numbers/66942242#66942242).

Comment: You should edit your question to add more details on the kind of distribution you have in mind.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in literally infinite number of ways. One other approach is to generate a number from binomial distribution, multiply with 450 and add 50. I will leave the task of finding the right parameters for the binomial distribution to you.

Comment: Okay, ty. I have a limited understanding of distribution types. In the end, I went with a linear distribution between minimum and average, then average and maximum, then chose one of the values randomly. I was hoping to do it with a single algorithm, but I'll need to get back into math first, I think.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I calculate a random number between 50 and 500, with an average result of 100?

You can use Chi-squared of degree 4 with its tail removed.
It is very easy to calculate.

```
local function random_50_500()
   -- result is from 50 to 500
   -- mean is very near to 100
   local x
   repeat
      x = math.log(math.random()) + math.log(math.random())
   until x > -18
   return x * -25 + 50
end
```